# Why are Dueling Q Networks not used more often to approximate Q-values in reinforcement learning algorithms?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-rl

I've just learned about [Dueling Network Architectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06581) to estimate $Q$-values and am wondering why this architecture is not used more often in deep RL algorithms? DDPG and TD3 estimate the $Q$-function using Double Q Learning instead of the empirically better Dueling Approach.